# Java OpenAL - Source gain of zero after passing the max distance

Tags: java, audio, interpolation, lwjgl, openal

(Sorry for my bad English)

Hi, I'm learning [LWJGL 3](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki) [OpenAL](https://openal.org/documentation/) library.

Playing around with the 3D audio attenuation, I noticed that you can't get a gain of zero for a source using a good realistic distance model like `AL_INVERSE_DISTANCE_CLAMPED`:

[image: 3]

I can achieve this using the `AL_LINEAR_DISTANCE_CLAMPED` because after the `AL_MAX_DISTANCE` the source gain is zero:

[image: 4]

But this is a very bad and unrealistic model....

So, is there a way to have a `AL_INVERSE_DISTANCE_CLAMPED` model but with a gain of zero after passing the `AL_MAX_DISTANCE`? Something like this:

[image: 5]

Here's a very simplified example of my current code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;

import static org.lwjgl.openal.AL.*;
import static org.lwjgl.openal.AL10.*;
import static org.lwjgl.openal.ALC11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.openal.ALC.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        // some init stuff from the docs
        long device;
        long context;
        
        String deviceName = alcGetString(0, ALC_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);
        
        device = alcOpenDevice(deviceName);
        context = alcCreateContext(device, new int[]{0});
        
        alcMakeContextCurrent(context);
        createCapabilities(createCapabilities(device));
        
        
        alDistanceModel(AL_INVERSE_DISTANCE_CLAMPED);   // using inverse distance clamped model
        
        int source = alGenSources();    // create a source
        alSource3f(source, AL_POSITION, 0, 0, 0);   // set the source position to 0
        
        // source values to work with the distance model
        alSourcef(source, AL_ROLLOFF_FACTOR, 1f);   // the rolloff factor makes some changes to the gain curve: the higher the rolloff, the steeper the curve will be
        alSourcef(source, AL_REFERENCE_DISTANCE, 5f);   // the reference distance determines the distance between source and listener where the gain is exactly 1
        //alSourcef(source, AL_MAX_DISTANCE, 15f);      // after this distance between source and listener, the sound won't be attenuated anymore in the clamped models
                                                        // I leave this value commented because it would be exactly what I don't want
        
        alSourcef(source, AL_GAIN, 1f);     // set the gain of the sound to 1
        alSourcei(source, AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE); // loop the sound
        
        
        // now let's load the audio file
        int audioBuffer = alGenBuffers();   // we'll store the buffer id of the sound in this variable
        // load the audio file to an AudioInputStream
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/sound.wav")));
        
        AudioFormat audioFormat = stream.getFormat();
        int format, sampleRate, bytesPerFrame, totalBytes;
        // OpenAL needs a ByteBuffer to fill its buffer with readable data, so now we need to convert the AudioInputStream to a ByteBuffer and some audio infos
        ByteBuffer data;
        
        format = AL_FORMAT_MONO16;  // for simplicity, I set the format to mono16 but there are some other ways to get the right format
        sampleRate = (int)audioFormat.getSampleRate();
        bytesPerFrame = audioFormat.getFrameSize();
        totalBytes = (int)stream.getFrameLength() * bytesPerFrame;
        
        data = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(totalBytes);
        
        // read the stream and put the data in the ByteBuffer
        byte[] temp = new byte[totalBytes];
        int read = stream.read(temp, 0, totalBytes);
        data.clear();
        data.put(temp, 0, read);
        data.flip();    // flip the buffer, otherwise OpenAL won't be able to read it
        
        stream.close(); // close the stream, we don't need it anymore
        
        alBufferData(audioBuffer, format, data, sampleRate);    // now we can finally send the audio data to OpenAL
        
        
        alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, audioBuffer);  // tell the source to play this sound
        
        
        float listenerX = -20f;
        alListener3f(AL_POSITION, listenerX, 0, 2); // set the initial listener position to -20 on the x and 2 on the z to have a nice 3D audio transition between the channels
        
        alSourcePlay(source);   // play the sound
        
        while(listenerX < 50) {
            listenerX += .05f;  // move the listener on the X axis
            alListener3f(AL_POSITION, listenerX, 0, 2);
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }

}
```

If you run this code, you'll notice that even when the listener is 50 units far away from the source the sound still clearly audible! I'd like to have a maximum distance from the source where the listener won't be able anymore to hear the sound but without suddently setting the gain to 0.

#### **Is there any way to do it?**

## **UPDATE 1:**

I discovered that the gain of the source set by `distance model` is overwrote by the source gain (the one defined in this way: `alSourcef(source, AL_GAIN, gain)`). So if I set the source gain to `0f`, the distance model will interpolate with a maximum gain value of zero, so there won't be any sound.

So I tried to actually merge the `AL_INVERSE_DISTANCE_CLAMPED` model with the `AL_LINEAR_DISTANCE_CLAMPED` model. I'm not good at drawing these graphs but it should be something like that:
[image: 6]
The blue curve works like a "limiter" for the green curve.

So, the `blue` curve is made by linearly interpolating the source gain from `1f` to `0f` based on the distance between source and listener. The `green` curve is made by the distance model.

Here's how I implemented this based on the example code I provided before:

First let's create some variables

```
float rolloff = 1f;
float maxDistance = 20f;
float referenceDistance = 5;
float gain = 1f;    // the source gain. It will work as a "limiter" for the distance model
```

Now we have to set our `distance model` and then give `rolloff`, `maxDistance` and `referenceDistance` to OpenAL

```
alDistanceModel(AL_INVERSE_DISTANCE_CLAMPED);   // using inverse distance clamped model
alSourcef(source, AL_ROLLOFF_FACTOR, rolloff);  // the rolloff factor makes some changes to the gain curve: the higher the rolloff, the steeper the curve will be
alSourcef(source, AL_MAX_DISTANCE, maxDistance);        // after this distance between source and listener, the sound won't be attenuated anymore in the clamped models
alSourcef(source, AL_REFERENCE_DISTANCE, referenceDistance);   // the reference distance determines the distance between source and listener where the gain is exactly 1
```

Now in the while loop we first find the distance between the source and the listener

```
float distance = (float)Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
```

To calculate the distance we can easily find the source and listener coords in this way. Use `alGetListener3f(param, buffX, buffY, buffZ)` to get listener coords or `alGetSource3f(source, param, buffX, buffY, buffZ)` passing as first parameter the source ID

```
public Vector3f getPosition3f() {
    FloatBuffer bufferX = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(1);
    FloatBuffer bufferY = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(1);
    FloatBuffer bufferZ = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(1);
    alGetListener3f(AL_POSITION, bufferX, bufferY, bufferZ);
    return new Vector3f(bufferX.get(0), bufferY.get(0), bufferZ.get(0));
}
```

At this point we must calculate the gain given the distance. I'm not a pro in math, so this could be a bit weird but it works

```
if(distance > 0) gain = 1 - (distance - referenceDistance) / (maxDistance - referenceDistance);
else gain = 1 + (distance + referenceDistance) / (maxDistance - referenceDistance);
```

The gain could now get below zero or over one, so we need to check this

```
if(gain < 0) gain = 0;
else if(gain > 1) gain = 1;
```

Finally we can set the source gain!

```
alSourcef(source, AL_GAIN, gain);
```

#### So, Why I'm not using this as an answer?

Applying this into a `Game Loop` context, I'm afraid it could slow down the game and weigh heavily on the CPU having to calculate the gain in the same thread for each source at each update. Imagine if for example in the game there was a stable full of animals making noises at the same time. I think it would be difficult for the CPU to do all this in addition to the other update tasks.

**mini-update:** I just tried this solution on my PC and as I expected, over 300 active sources the game starts to freeze and lag (using an i9-9900k)

Comment: It might be beneficial to provide a simple example of your current programme. If someone out there can help it will avoid them having to do any heavy lifting. Also, little quality of life edits like linking to LWJGL OpenAL docs will reduce the barriers to help. Helpful people on SO are inherently lazy, so it is worth keeping that in mind

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I'm gonna edit providing an example and some useful links.

Comment: This question has spiralled a bit and you may need to go back to the drawing board and refine what it is you are asking. Likely you are asking multiple question, which should have individual SO posts, rather than a single succinct one.

Comment: On the question of sources, I think you may need to start thinking like a sound designer and not a programmer. Taking the _stable of animals_ example, if I had 300 “animals” (models) I’d probably limit the source position to the closest `n` then have a generic ambient sound diffused from origin. Sound localisation has its limits and OpenAL isn’t cutting edge. I wouldn’t expect a listener to meaningfully localise 20 sound sources let alone 300.

Comment: @fdcpp yeah, it makes sense... I think I'll just do this, at least for now. Should I edit the question in some way in order to "reduce the questions"? And should I make an answer using my update 1 solution and your sound designer solution?

Comment: It’ll sting because of the bounty loss, but I’d copy the question for yourself to personally tear it apart and then ideally delete this one (wait until the bounty expires, you never know if someone out there has an answer). You can then look towards splitting the question apart into as many separate problems as possible. Some of those won’t be programming based so don’t forget about the rest of SE, e.g [Sound Design Stack Exchange](https://sound.stackexchange.com/). You’ve done an ace job of exploring this overall project, so don’t be disheartened.

Comment: @fdcpp ok, thanks!